# MS Access FInd Duplicates

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a MS Access table that had duplicate entries loaded to it. I used the query wizard and it returns both records. I need to return one record preferably with the id so I can use it to delete only the duplicate. Its been awhile since I used MS Access can this be done?

```
 UpdateTable
   ID
   PkgId
   CompName
   UpdDate   
   UpdQty
```

Data:

```
7212797   ADJ  E5780   9/27/2019 7;  
7213166   ADJ  E5780   9/27/2019 7; 
7212708   ADJ  E5912   9/27/2019 7;
7213167   ADJ  E5912   9/27/2019 7;
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing my question looks a lot better

Answer (score 0):

Consider the approach using a correlated subquery with an `EXISTS` condition:

```
SELECT id
FROM mytable t
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM mytable t1
    WHERE 
        t1.PkgId = t.PkgId 
        AND t1.CompName = t.CompName
        AND t1.UpdDate = t.UpdDate
        AND t1.UpdQty = t.UpdQty
        AND t1.id < t.id
)
```

This will return all `id` for which a duplicate exists (ie same `pkgId/CompName/UpdDate/UpdQty`). The record with the lowest `id` is considered the original record and will not be returned by the query.

Comment: This worked but I need to return the entire duplicate record so I can report back the counts out of inventory, and do some reporting as to what I am deleting. But this does answer the original question. I would up vote the answer but I don't have enough points

Comment: @WilliamBurke: ok then you can just replace `SELECT id` by `SELECT t.*`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the records, there are multiple ways.  I would go for a comparison on the `id` column:

```
delete from t
    where t.id < (select max(t2.id)
                  from t as t2
                  where t2.compname = t.compname and
                        t2.upddate = t.update and
                        t2.updqty = t.updqty and
                 );
```

That said, this will not work if any of the comparison columns are `null`.  If `id` is a primary key, you can instead use:

```
delete from t
    where t.id not in (select max(t2.id)
                       from t t2
                       group by pkgid, compname, upddate
                      );
```